# proper usage of apostrophe in sql statements to call combo box

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

how can i change the 'COMP' to be check on what i chose on combo box category?

My textbox is cmbCategory

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory Where CAT_ID='COMP'", sqlconn)
If sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlconn.Open()
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
sdr.Close()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7351135/139010

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentSubCategory Where CAT_ID=@Category", sqlconn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = cmbCategory.SelectedText
If sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlconn.Open()
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
sdr.Close()
```

Comment: sir it returned error

Additional information: Invalid parameter Size value '-1'. The value must be greater than or equal to 0.

may i note that. this is for a combo box that when i chose a category it will display the corresponding subcategory on combo box 2

Comment: Set `size` to 1000 or whatever you need: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000)`