# How to solve incorrect syntax in sql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using this code

```
cn.Open()

Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(AdmissionNumber, FullName, DOBirth, Class_Stream, DateAdmitted, Gender, County, KCPEYear, KCPEIndex, Phone1, Phone2, PostalAddress, PostalCode, Town, EmailAddress, AnyOtherInformation, StudentPhoto) VALUES ('" & Tbx12.Text & "','" & Tbx30.Text & "','" & Tbx4.Text & "','" & Tbx31.Text & "','" & Tbx13.Text & "','" & Cbx1.SelectedItem & "','" & Cbx2.SelectedItem & "','" & Cbx4.SelectedItem & "','" & Tbx15.Text & "','" & Tbx6.Text & "','" & Tbx7.Text & "','" & Tbx8.Text & "','" & Tbx9.Text & "','" & Tbx10.Text & "','" & Tbx11.Text & "','" & Rtbx1.Text & "',@StudentPhoto)", cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdmissionNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx12.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx30.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOBirth", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx4.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Class_Stream", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx31.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateAdmitted", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx13.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@County", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KCPEYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx4.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KCPEIndex", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx15.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx6.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx7.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx8.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx9.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Town", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx10.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx11.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("AnyOtherInformation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rtbx1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@StudentPhoto", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)

    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using
```

to save data to SQL Server. I am suspecting that the error I got is because at Textbox30, Combobox2 and Textbox10 can contain User Inputs with Apostrophes. Eg. Murang'a, Ndung'u, How will I solve this?

Comment: You are actually not implementing it right. Look up a tutorial of Prepared Statements

Comment: @ juergen d. Kindly Send me the link.

Comment: Just google: *prepared statements example vb*

Comment: Check out [this other SO question (and its answers!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351135/prepared-statements-in-vb-net) for a first glimpse. You're using *parameters* - which is good - but you don't use them in your `INSERT` statement! (which is horribly bad)

Comment: @Replace the string concatenation in the values clause with parameter names: `VALUES(@AdmissionNumber, @FullName,...)`.  The actual values used for the `INSERT` will be the parameter values.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with parameters in an insert statement.

Comment: You really should set the length of your varchar parameters. And you seem to be using the image datatype. It has been deprecated since 2005 in favor of varbinary(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your problem is that you **concatenate** together your `INSERT` statement (which is a **horribly bad** practice - opens the doors for SQL injection attacks - still the **#1** attacks out on the web!), while in the statements below, you're actually adding parameters (which aren't present in your `INSERT` query above.....).

So change your code to this:

```vb
cn.Open()

' use INSERT statement *WITH* parameters!
Dim insertQry as string = 
    "INSERT INTO Students(AdmissionNumber, FullName, DOBirth, Class_Stream, DateAdmitted, Gender, County, " &
                         "KCPEYear, KCPEIndex, Phone1, Phone2, PostalAddress, PostalCode, Town, EmailAddress, AnyOtherInformation, StudentPhoto) " &
    "VALUES (@AdmissionNumber, @FullName, @DOBirth, @Class_Stream, @DateAdmitted, @Gender, @County, " &
                         "@KCPEYear, @KCPEIndex, @Phone1, @Phone2, @PostalAddress, @PostalCode, @Town, " &
                         "@EmailAddress, @AnyOtherInformation, @StudentPhoto);";

Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(insertQry, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdmissionNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx12.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx30.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOBirth", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx4.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Class_Stream", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx31.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateAdmitted", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx13.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@County", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KCPEYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Cbx4.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@KCPEIndex", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx15.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx6.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx7.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx8.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx9.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Town", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx10.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Tbx11.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AnyOtherInformation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rtbx1.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudentPhoto", SqlDbType.Image).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)

    i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End Using
```

and then you should be fine - safely protected from SQL injection attacks, handling names with apostrophes quite nicely, and it'll be faster, too! (if you execute the same insert more than once)

Comment: Note this row: `cmd.Parameters.Add("AnyOtherInformation", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Rtbx1.Text` is missing a `@` in the parameter name definition.

Comment: np. didn't see your answer when I posted mine, only after posting it. since it's basically the same I'm deleting mine and upvoting yours.

Comment: Zohar av noted the missing @. Av also noted your gentleman action to Marc_S. @ Marc_s, Thumbs up.

Comment: Also a slight syntax error at @StudentPhoto);"; Should it be @StudentPhoto)"

Comment: @HenryGathigira: actually, it's *good practice* to end your SQL statements with a `;` - so that semicolon is there *on purpose*, and it *should be there*, too!