# Insert data into MySQL database using parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Recently I developed some software that inserts data into MySQL but someone told me I should use parameters. I Googled them but didn't found any data.

Here is my code:

```
Dim Query As String
Query = "insert into baza.artikli(kod,naziv,nabavna,prodazna,ddv,kolicina,opis,opis2,mkproizvod,profit,proizvoditel) values ('" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & kupovnacena & "','" & prodaznacena & "','" & ddv & "','" & kolicina & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis2.Text & "','" & mkpr & "','" & profit & "','" & TextBoxProizvoditel.Text & "')"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent injection

Here's an example

```
Dim query As String

query = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES(?);"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Me.User_nameTextBox.Text)
//Execute your command......
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check on `Prepared Statements`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Or refer 
[Prepared Statements in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351135/prepared-statements-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use SQL parameters. This is to reduce syntax issues but more importantly stops SQL injection. See [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) for more details on this.

I've also noted that you're using `ExecuteReader`. This is generally used for select statements. For inserts and updates you should use `ExecuteNonQuery`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) for more information.

If you haven't already I also suggest you implement [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

With these changes your code would look something like this:

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection(yourConnectionString),
      cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO baza.artikli (kod, naziv, nabavna, prodazna, ddv, kolicina, opis, opis2, mkproizvod, profit, proizvoditel) VALUES (@kod, @naziv, @nabavna, @prodazna, @ddv, @kolicina, @opis, @opis2, @mkproizvod, @profit, @proizvoditel)", con)

    con.Open()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@kod", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBoxBarkod.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@naziv", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBoxNaziv.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@nabavna", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = kupovnacena
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodazna", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = prodaznacena
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ddv", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = ddv
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@kolicina", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = kolicina
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@opis", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBoxOpis.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@opis2", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBoxOpis2.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mkproizvod", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = mkpr
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@profit", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = profit
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@proizvoditel", MySqlDbType.[Type]).Value = TextBoxProizvoditel.Text

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Using
```

> Note that I have used `MySqlDbType.[Type]`. You will want to replace `[Type]` with the data type you've used on your database.

Answer (score -1):

To answer you first question:
Set

```
TextBoxBarkod.Text = "(select password from mysql.user where user=’root’)"
```

Or in other words: Search the web for [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

For an example how to use parameters see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351229/4546677).

Comment: This wont work, didnt supply all fields...the insert would fail and the select wont happen. If the insert only had one column, then yes it would work...

Comment: Good point, at least it would have generated an error ;-). Made some changes.