# Inserting data to MySQL VB .NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, modbus

So, I'm doing a project where I have to read data from a PLC with modbus protocol and insert the data into a database in this case MySQL.
I'm having no trouble reading the modbus data and inserting into MySQL using for loop.
However I have to insert probably around 1000 data per second into the database.
I tried doing 100 data and it took around 5 second for the all the data to be inserted into my table.
Is there any ways to insert the data quicker? or is it the limit of MySQL database?
I tried using SQL Server too, it took around 1.5 seconds to insert 100 data into the table

Here's my code:

```
myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;" _
            & "uid=root;" _
           & "pwd=;" _
          & "database=modbus"
    modbus.IPAddress = "192.168.18.70"
    modbus.Port = 502
    Do
        If modbus.Connected = False Then
            Try
                modbus.Connect()
                If modbus.Connected Then

                    Label1.Text = "Connected"
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Label1.Text = "Disconnected"
            End Try
        End If


        If conn.State = 0 Then
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Label2.Text = conn.State
            Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
                Label2.Text = conn.State

            End Try

        End If

        If modbus.Connected Then


            Dim Regvals As Integer()
            Dim regvals2 As Integer()
            Dim regvals3 As Integer()
            Dim regvals4 As Integer()
            Dim regvals5 As Integer()
            Dim regvals6 As Integer()
            Dim regvals7 As Integer()
            Dim regvals8 As Integer()
            Dim regvals9 As Integer()
            Dim regvals10 As Integer()
            Dim sql As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer
            Dim k As Integer
            Dim tgl As String

            Try
                Regvals = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 100)
                regvals2 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(100, 100)
                regvals3 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(200, 100)
                regvals2 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(300, 100)
                regvals3 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(400, 100)
                regvals2 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(500, 100)
                regvals3 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(600, 100)
                regvals2 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(700, 100)
                regvals3 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(800, 100)
                regvals10 = modbus.ReadHoldingRegisters(900, 100)
                modbus.Disconnect()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


            If Regvals.Length > 0 Then

                i = 0
                j = 0
                k = 0
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                '
                For Each value As Integer In Regvals
                    tgl = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(value)


                    sql = "insert into test values('" & tgl & "'," & i & "," & Regvals(i) & ")"
                    i = i + 1
                    cmd.Connection = conn
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sql = ""
                    Label3.Text = i


                Next

                If regvals2.Length > 0 Then
                    For Each value As Integer In regvals2
                        tgl = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
                        '

                        sql = "insert into test values('" & tgl & "'," & i & "," & regvals2(j) & ")"
                        j = j + 1
                        i = i + 1
                        cmd.Connection = conn
                        cmd.CommandText = sql
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        sql = ""
                        Label3.Text = i


                    Next

                End If

                If regvals3.Length > 0 Then
                    For Each value As Integer In regvals3
                        tgl = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
                        '
                        '
                        sql = "insert into test values('" & tgl & "'," & i & "," & regvals3(k) & ")"
                        i = i + 1
                        k = k + 1
                        cmd.Connection = conn
                        cmd.CommandText = sql
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        sql = ""
                        Label3.Text = i


                    Next

                End If

            End If
        End If



    Loop
```

Comment: open the ConnectionString and close it out of the loop .. don't open and close it with every insert command

Comment: what connection? the Modbus connection? I don't close the MySQL Connection

Comment: Using a [prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351135/prepared-statements-in-vb-net) may help but, due to the number of separate `insert` operations, I suspect that building one large insert (that inserts all data retrieved in that iteration) will be even better. Each query you send requires a network transaction (request, response) which takes time; generally one big query will be faster than lots of small ones. Also look at your database schema (for example minimise indexes and constraints because these will slow down inserts).

Comment: You could investigate table adapters, although I feel improvement might be negligible.  Maybe a bulk sql statement might be worth looking into

Comment: Construct your insert statement to run only once. INSERT INTO xxxxxx (field1,field2) values ('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f') etc.

Comment: thanks guys, I used the run only once insert into xxx values(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)....(y.z) sql command instead of doing insert in the loop