# How to print current data record from form VB .NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

hi I am new in programming and I hope all with respect to help me
I create a form with vb.net EX: "main Branches " and I want to print current data record so I create another form and put RDCL report in it
and it is run well but showing all record. i want the report show only the current record

note:-

- if i remove where condition the report show all data and if i use where condition it does not show any record

  ' the form which contain the record '
  Private Sub BTN_PRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_PRINT.Click

  ```
            Dim f As New Form1
            f.ShowDialog()



        End Sub

    ''the form which contain rdcl report ''

    Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load

            Dim codee As String = FRM_BR.TXT_code.Text
            Dim CON As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MOHAMEDTHRWAT20\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=data_egy;User ID=sa")
            Dim COM As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tb_br] where code ='" & codee & "' ", CON)
            Dim SD As New SqlDataAdapter(COM)
            Dim DTa As New DataTable

            SD.Fill(DTa)

            With Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
                .DataSources.Clear()
                .ReportPath = "C:\Users\mothr\onedrive\المستندات\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\PL\PL_ACC\Report1.rdlc"
                .DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DTa))

            End With
            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        End Sub
  ```

Comment: as you filter already for the code, it shouldn't show all data, but you can see when you haltafter the fill teh content of DTa. Please see also prepared statements https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351190/5193536 you code is vulnerable

Comment: You don't need a report to print some data. You can just use a PrintDocument, handle the PrintPage event and call Print.

Comment: _if i remove where condition the report show all data and if i use where condition it does not show any record_ To me, this would suggest that the value of codee is not actually contained in the tb_br table.  Being a string you will need to make sure character casing matches.  Maybe using something like Upper() of both sides of the where condition might be enough